# Turn Enterprise Keyword column into clickable links

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata

I've created an Enterprise Keyword column and have begun tagging documents. My conception was that terms in the column would automatically be clickable links and allow users to see all files tagged with a term by clicking on it. 
But that is not the case. 
So, how can I achieve this?